# Is there way to get just the DateTime Format(Pattern) String in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

I need to display just the format of Datetime and not the actual datetime.

Comment: Use `moment.js`

Comment: can you explain with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Is your question is looking into the date like 01/12/2009 how to know the format of it?

Not possible. Why: 01/01/2001 is DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY?